# Error while retrieving an encrypted message

Tags: encryption, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework, ejabberd-module

I am using ejabberd 15.11. While a client is trying to retrieve message from archive getting below error in error logs. My client is sending and receiving encrypted messages

**Error log:**

```
[error] <0.2337.0>@gen_iq_handler:process_iq:128
{
    {badmatch,{error,{4,<<"not well-formed (invalid token)">>}}},
    [
        {mod_mam,'-select/8-fun-4-',3,[{file,"src/mod_mam.erl"},{line,681}]},
        {lists,map,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1237}]},
        {mod_mam,select,8,[{file,"src/mod_mam.erl"},{line,677}]},
        {mod_mam,select_and_send,10,[{file,"src/mod_mam.erl"},{line,577}]},
        {gen_iq_handler,process_iq,6,[{file,"src/gen_iq_handler.erl"},{line,127}]},
        {gen_iq_handler,handle_info,2,[{file,"src/gen_iq_handler.erl"},{line,171}]},
        {gen_server,try_dispatch,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,593}]},
        {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,659}]}
    ]
}
```

Comment: How are you saving message in archive ? Do you write them outside of ejabberd ?

Comment: and what is the typical size of your encrypted messages ?

Comment: I have closed this issue here because i was using   crypto:block_encrypt(Type, Key, Ivec, PlainText)
.

Comment: I guess you mean that you were not crypting / uncrypting properly, generating malformed XML in the stream. Maybe you should I a full answer and marked it as resolved to help future developers ?

Comment: i switched too  crypto:aes_cfb_128_encrypt(_, _, _) though at compile time it is resulting as deprecated function warning . but i am able to encrypt and decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

crypto:block_encrypt(Type, Key, Ivec, PlainText)is not working insted of it try to use crypto:aes_cfb_128_encrypt(Key, Ivec, PlainText) function.